# How to solve a system of linear equations exactly?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Given a system of equations, 
$$\frac{dR}{dt}=-aR+bJ, \quad \frac{dJ}{dt}=-aJ+bR,$$
I have to discuss what happens to their love(Romeo  and Juliet mathematical modeling exercise) is their caution $a$ is larger than their responsiveness $b$, and if $a$ is smaller than $b$. I've been given the option to solve this system exactly or by method of equilibrium and its stability.  I'm choosing to go with solving it exactly since I'm still trying to understand the concept of phase planes and phase portraits.  Solving it exactly seems like it would just be a method that I have previously learned but can't figure out which.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating the first equation,
$$ R''=-aR'+bJ'. $$
Substituting from the second equation and then the first equation,
$$ R''+aR'=b(-aJ+bR) = b^2 R -a(bJ)=b^2R - a(R'+aR) $$
Hence
$$ R''+2aR'+(a^2-b^2)R=0, $$
which has general solution $Ae^{-at}\cosh{bt} + Be^{-at} \sinh{bt}$
Since the equations are linear, you can insert this into the $J$ equation to find the corresponding solutions for $J$:
$$ J'+aJ = be^{-at}(A\cosh{bt}+B\sinh{bt}). $$
Multiplying by $e^{at}$,
$$ (e^{at}J)' = b(A\cosh{bt}+B\sinh{bt}), \\
e^{at}J = A\sinh{bt}+B\cosh{bt}) + C, $$
so $J = e^{-at}A\sinh{bt}+B\cosh{bt}) + Ce^{-at}$.
We can see that $C$ is zero from $R'=-aR+bJ$.

Comment: Thanks! but how did you determine that C is zero from that equation?

Comment: @Jaider There are no terms with a $C$ in $R$, so nothing can cancel with it.

Comment: Whereas the $A$ and $B$ terms cancel out.

Comment: I'm not getting the same general solution as you are, I'm getting R=Ae^(-a+2b)+Be^(-a-2b). Care to explain how you determine your general solution?

Comment: I notice I had a typo ($2aR$ should be $2aR'$ in the equation for $R$). The auxiliary equation is $k^2 + 2ak +(a^2-b^2)=0$, and the quadratic formula for an equation of the form $x^2+2bx+c=0$ is $x=-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-c}$, which gives in this case $a\pm b$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining to me how you got your general solution?

Comment: You can either write it in terms of the exponentials $e^{(-a\pm b)t}$, or another set of solutions is $e^{-at}\cosh{bt},e^{-at}\sinh{bt}$, for the same reason that you can use either $\cos{x}$ and $\sin{x}$ or $e^{\pm ix}$ to form a general solution to $y''+y=0$: you can get between them with a linear transformation.